# Responsiveness not working properly but only on mobile on landscape mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm quite new to both Web Development and Stack Overflow so I hope this question is not against any rules.

I'm creating a personal website while I learn Web Development and I'm having an issue with responsiveness. The website performs perfectly at all window sizes when I'm testing it on Google Dev tools. No matter how I resize my window using the Device Toolbar on Dev Tools everything that should be responsive works really nicely.

However, when I view the website on my iPhone 12 (haven't tested on other models) using either Safari or Chrome and **only on landscape** it starts behaving weirdly. The nav bar is supposed to always have a width of 100% of the browser width, both when expanded, i.e. at larger screen sizes and when the burger is not shown, and when collapsed, i.e. at smaller screens and when the burger is shown. However, on mobile when the page is loaded for the first time everything is fine but when you change to landscape and back to portrait the nav bar gets reduced, i.e. not occupying the full width of the browser.

I can't figure out why...

The website can be accessed here: [www.imtiago.world](http://www.imtiago.world)
The source code is here: https://github.com/brandaspt/brandaspt.github.io

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:
I guess the issue is with my nav bar because the same is happening with this live demo of just the nav bar: https://jsfiddle.net/2owsr9pz/
This my only media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .top-nav-links {
    display: none;
  }

  .top-nav-burger {
    display: block;
  }

  .close-button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Teemu the problem is that I have no idea about which part of the code has the problem. That's why I provided the GitHub repo containing all the files (html, css and js). Should I just paste all the code here in the post? Cause it will be quite long 

Comment: @Teemu please check the edit. Thank you

Comment: @Teemu the nav bar is supposed to always have a width of 100% of the browser width, both when expanded, i.e. at larger screen sizes and when the burger is not shown, and when collapsed, i.e. at smaller screens and when the burger is shown. However, on mobile when the page is loaded for the first time everything is fine but when you change to landscape and back to portrait the nav bar gets reduced, i.e. not occupying the full width of the browser. I guess it would be more clear if you were able to open the link on mobile and try yourself.

Comment: That's a good explanation, I've copied it to your question. Unfortunately I don't have iOS at hands, the code works well with Android, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use orientation in your css as well, from looking at your code, you only use screen size. Here's a demo of what a simple usage with screen size looks like.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Comment: the thing is that the website is supposed to behave in the exact same way either for landscape or portrait. If I did what you suggest I'd have the exact same code inside both media queries. Is this good practice?